# HLS Fairplay DRM content I got error to obtain licence key from DRM server by using videojs and videojs-contrib-eme

Tags: http-live-streaming, video.js, fairplay, eme

HLS Fairplay DRM Content videojs return `Failed to load resource: Origin https:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. when trying to get licence for HLS fairplay.

I am using Videojs version @7.5.5 and videojs-contrib-eme version @3.5.4

```
player.src({
            // normal Video.js src and type options
            src: streamUri,
            type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
            keySystems: {
                "com.apple.fps.1_0": {
                    certificateUri: certificateUri,
                    getLicense: function (emeOptions, contentId, keyMessage, callback) {
                        videojs.xhr({
                            uri: licenceUri,
                            method: 'POST',
                            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                            body: keyMessage,
                            headers: {
                                'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
                                'utoken-drm': 'fp'
                            }
                        }, function (err, response, responseBody) {
                            if (err) {
                                callback(err);
                                return;
                            }

                            callback(null, responseBody);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        player.play();'''
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS error. CORS is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) if you aren't familiar.

Is it your content? Did you set up the licence server?

Comment: Yes, You are right i have change the Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Error gone but there is another error which key session error